# What sofware to encrypt whole drives, Google drive folder, keeping access on Android and good performances?

Tags: windows, android, encryption, hard-disk, google-drive

I would like to encrypt my drives and data on Windows 10, but I need some recommendation to use the appropriate software(s).

- On my system drive, I have the `"Backup and sync"` Google software and the synchronized `Google Drive` folder. But I absolutely need to let the folder content readable from my phone at any time. If I encrypt the whole drive, will this folder be synchronized as encrypted? If yes, is it possible to decrypt files from `Google Drive` on the fly on Android?
- I also have a `"Media"` SSHD (with my `Pictures` and `Videos` folders, and video editing stuff), a `"Backup"` SSHD (which contains the `FileHistory` Windows folder), and a `"Virtual machines"` SSHD. Note that I need to keep good performances with all of them if I encrypt them, regardless of the method.

I think that the most important folders to encrypt are `Google Drive`, `Pictures`, `Videos` and `FileHistory`. But I don't know if whole drive encryption will be better and more appropriate.

For Windows, I found `"Bitlocker"` and `"VeraCrypt"`, but if all files are encrypted, I won't be able to decrypt `Google Drive` folder content on Android.

For `Google Drive`, I found `"Boxcryptor"`, `"Cryptomator"`, and `"GoodSync"` which work on Windows and Android, but which seems to be specific to cloud storage.

- What folders or drives must I/can I encrypt to keep good performances?
- What software(s) do you advise me to use? Do I have to use two sofwares to fit my requirements, or do you have any other recommendation?

Thanks!

Comment: @Izzy I edited the question, tell me if it's correct now.

Comment: Yes, thanks! That looks fine now. I'm not on Windows (my last Windows was more than 25 years ago, 3.11 :D), so I cannot help you further – but I wish you good luck (and will cleanup comments then).

Comment: I remember installing Windows 3.1 from 28 floppies :-) and developing commercial software for it, when working for Siemens. Happy days !